# Test with AutoData from base test fixture isn't run

Tags: nunit, autofixture

I use *Autofixture 3.21.0* and *AutoFixture.NUnit2 3.21.0* along with *NUnit 2.6.3* and *Resharper 8.2.3* runner.

I have implemented the generic base test fixture which contains a common set of tests for several production classes. It's something like the following:

```cs
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestsBase<T>
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_in_base_class()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }

        [Test, AutoData]
        public void Test_in_base_class_with_autodata( T obj )
        {
            // this test is not run !!!
            Assert.NotNull( obj );
        }
    }
```

One example concrete test fixture class which inherits from base test fixture class can be implemented as shown below:

```cs
    [TestFixture]
    public class DerivedTests : TestsBase<string>
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_in_derived_class()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }

        [Test, AutoData]
        public void Test_in_derived_class_with_autodata( string obj )
        {
            Assert.NotNull( obj );
        }
    }
```

When I run this derived test fixture using R# 8.2.3 runner, test method from base class which is attributed with *AutoDataAttribute* (named *Test_in_base_class_with_autodata*) is not run. All other test methods are invoked as expected but that from base class with *AutoDataAttribute*.

Have you had the same problem? Is it AutoFixture.Nunit2 bug? Is there a workaround for this issue? Please for help.

Comment: BTW There is the workaround. We can use NUnit's parametrized *TestFixtureAttribute* (i.e *[TestFixture(typeof(string))]* for base fixture class) rather than utilize fixtures inheritance. The drawback is that in this approach we have to maintain two test fixture classes for several types (one class for common test methods and one for specialized test methods) . So in my opinion in this case inheritance may lead to more concise solution. Anyway, It would be nice to know if we have faced AutoFixture bug or intentional behavior.

Comment: The new [issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/325) has been opened at Autofixture's GitHub homepage.